# Why is this Trigger not working

Tags: trigger, insert, debug

I've a question with this trigger. I checked the register and it launch the trigger but is not doing anything. It doesnt show me the debug messages, even the first one.

The idea is that when we are creating a new Account, it has to create an event.

Any help will be thankful.

Thanks everybody for your time.

```
trigger CreateActivity on Account (after insert){    

List<date> dateList = new List<date>();
List<Event> EventList = new List<Event>();
Util_Fechas parse = new Util_Fechas();

system.debug('It is in the Trigger');
for(Account acc : Trigger.new){
    system.debug('It is in the For');
    if(acc.CustomField__c != null){
        system.debug('It is in the If');
        string day = 'Tuesday';
        integer coef = 1;
        Date LookedDay = parse.rellenar_datelist(day, coef);
        system.debug(LookedDay);
        dateList.add(LookedDay);
        EventList.add(new Event(
            //OwnerId = acc.CreateById,
            WhatId = acc.Id,
            CustomField2__c = 'Whatever',
            ActivityDate = LookedDay,
            DurationInMinutes = 60
        ));
    }
}
insert EventList;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a workflow rule to create a task?

Comment: Thanks martin,
I'm checking right now. But i would like to know two different things:
1- Why is a workflow more appropriate than a trigger?
2- If it is... anyway, where is my mistake in this code?

It's important to me learning as much as possible.
Thanks again!

Comment: Are you getting an exception ? if not did you trigger arrive correctly at system.debug('It is in the If'); ?

Comment: No Amit Bangad; the trigger doesnt arrive even to ("it is in the trigger") but in the register it is created:
"Operación /setup/build/viewApexTrigger.apexp"

Comment: nop... the trigger is not being launched... :S

Comment: 1. It all depends on what you are trying to do. In general though, if you can use a workflow you should use a workflow. 2. Just looking at it, with what I can see here, I don't see any reason that this code wouldn't work.

Comment: Is the trigger active? The ui for some reason deactivates triggers each time you edit them.

Comment: put try / catch around the insert EventList. I think you are missing some required fields. But as Amit says best is not to use Apex. I would use Process Builder.

Comment: @martin was right! So noob of me... It was not active, anyway Michael Gill i have some missing required fields. THANKS ALL. I will write again when i'll finish!

Comment: How can i up your score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you edit a trigger in the ui, the trigger is automatically deactivated and you need to manually re-check the checkbox.

Honestly, this is more a bug in the salesforce ui than anything. It's left me scratching my head dozens of times before I got in the habit of looking for it.

Comment: That's a bug. I almost never create triggers that way. Use Mavesn/Sublime

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works!

What was happening?

1. @martin: The ui for some reason deactivates triggers each time you edit them
2. @Michael Gill: I think you are missing some required fields.

Noob problems.

Thank you all.

Comment: I would still do the process and not the trigger.